# Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 2023

Tags: kotlin, date, datetime, locale, datetimepicker

I am using numberPicker to display dates like;

```
val numberPicker = binding.numberPicker
val values = getArrayDates(date.toString()) //EventsBottomSheet.kt:45
numberPicker.minValue = 0
numberPicker.maxValue = values.size - 1
numberPicker.displayedValues = values.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(values.size))
numberPicker.wrapSelectorWheel = true
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener { _, _, newVal ->
    binding.dateText.text = newVal.toString()
}
```

getArrayDates function;

```
private fun getArrayDates(referenceDate : String) : ArrayList<String>{
    val datesList = referenceDate.split("/")
    val localeDate = LocalDate.of(datesList[0].toInt(), Month.of(datesList[1].toInt()), datesList[2].toInt()) //EventsBottomSheet.kt:65 (related with exception)
    val monthsToDisplay = listOf(localeDate.minusMonths(1), localeDate, localeDate.plusMonths(1))
    val daysList = ArrayList<String>()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
    for (month in monthsToDisplay) {
        val yearMonth = YearMonth.from(month)
        for (day in 1..yearMonth.lengthOfMonth()) {
            daysList.add(yearMonth.atDay(day).format(formatter))
        }
    }
    return daysList
}
```

I am observing "date" value like "21/05/2023" for example. And i turned it to a LocaleDate. But i am getting this error;

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.ahmetkaan.kediy, PID: 19391
                                                                                                    j$.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 2023
                                                                                                        at j$.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(ValueRange.java:311)
                                                                                                        at j$.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:713)
                                                                                                        at j$.time.LocalDate.of(LocalDate.java:250)
                                                                                                        at com.ahmetkaan.kediy.EventsBottomSheet.getArrayDates(EventsBottomSheet.kt:65)
                                                                                                        at com.ahmetkaan.kediy.EventsBottomSheet.onCreateView(EventsBottomSheet.kt:45)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.performCreateView(DialogFragment.java:510)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

First, i thought thats why can be that the zeros at the starts like "03/05/2023 etc." But i tried with "13/12/2023" and i am still getting this error. By the way, the error is not about for example, the absence of 30 in February. Because date value is defined with LocaleDate in past fragments. So How can i fix this?

Comment: The error tells you what the invalid value is: 2023. You are inputting the year as a day of month.

Comment: Don’t use `split()` for parsing the string into a `LocalDate`. Parsing is built in. Use `LocalDate.parse("03/05/2023", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in setting/declaring the localDate. In this line,

```
  val localeDate = LocalDate.of(datesList[0].toInt(), Month.of(datesList[1].toInt()), datesList[2].toInt()) //EventsBottomSheet.kt:65 (related with exception)
```

First, the reference for the LocalDate.of(),

```
 public static LocalDate of(int year, Month month, int dayOfMonth) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

So, when setting it or declaring it, you must input first the year, next is the month, lastly is for the day.

The line of code should be look like this (When you are inputting in this format "21/05/2023"):

```
val localeDate = LocalDate.of(datesList[2].toInt(), Month.of(datesList[1].toInt()), datesList[0].toInt())
```

Year first, then month, then dayOfMonth.

Hope this helps.